# Array Maximum Index Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Is there a way to set the maximum index size of an array. For example I have an array of UIImage but I only want the array to store 6 images. How would I set a restriction on that array so it can only hold 6 images

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035193/swift-create-a-fixed-length-array-enforced-at-compile-time or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395105/how-to-create-a-fixed-size-array-of-objects.

Comment: if you really need compile-time checked constant length arrays, I recommend looking into dependent types, [this great article](https://bigonotetaking.wordpress.com/2015/09/04/in-which-i-misunderstand-dependent-types/) is just about what you want (there even is a Playground version of it :D)

Comment: @Kametrixom Thank you I will look into that! XD

Answer (score 1):

There is no such functionality.  You would have to implement it yourself:

```
if array.count < 6 {
    array.append(element)
}
```

or perhaps:

```
while array.count >= 6 {
    array.removeFirst()
}
array.append(element)
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized this just after I posted the question

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your array with size of 6 and then do any one of the following checks:

- Check element count of the array before inserting new element
- You can surround your insertion code with try / catch block with 'ArrayIndexOutOfBounds' Exception being handled

Comment: You can't catch such an error in Swift.. Only functions which `throw` can throw an error